# Generate Float Random Values (also negative)

Tags: c, random

How can i generate float random values in C? (**also negative**)

Comment: what do you have so far?

Comment: I just generated values ​​from 0 to x ... not negative

Comment: Do you want a C or a C++ answer? They are likely to be very different. Please remove the tag that isn't relevant.

Comment: you're right, i need a C answer! I also adjusted the tag!

Comment: @Zany-Present or show what you have done so far?  Don't just post the question in it without showing your previous what you had tried so far.Just take it as an Advice

Comment: ok, forgive me. but i not posted what I did because it was a simple rand()...however, thank you for the Advice, I'll try to be more careful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general to generate random numbers from an arbitrary distribution you'd first generate uniform random numbers and then pass them to the inverse of the cumulative distribution function.

Assume for example that you want random numbers with uniform distribution on the interval [-10.0, 10.0] and all you've got is random numbers from [0.0, 1.0]. Cumulative distribution function of the uniform distribution on [-10.0, 10.0] is:

```
cdf(x) = 0.05 * x + 0.5   for x in [-10.0, 10.0]
```

This expresses the probability that a random number generated is smaller than x. The inverse is

```
icdf(y) = 20.0 * y - 10.0   for y in [0.0, 1.0]
```

(You can obtain this easily on paper by switching the x and y axis).

Hence to obtain random numbers uniformly distributed on [-10.0, 10.0] you can use the following code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

// Returns uniformly distributed random numbers from [0.0, 1.0].
double uniform0to1Random() {
    double r = random();
    return r / ((double)RAND_MAX + 1);
}

// Returns uniformly distributed random numbers from [-10.0, 10.0].
double myRandom() {
  return 20.0 * uniform0to1Random() - 10.0;
}
```

In fact, you don't need uniform0to1Random() since there are already a lot of good uniform random numbers generators from [0.0, 1.0] (e.g. in the boost library).

You can use the method to generate random numbers with nearly any probability distribution you want by sampling the inverse cumulative distribution as shown above.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling for more details.

Comment: make srand((signed)time(NULL)); //usually it is unsigned

Answer (score 2):

**Edit** Since the question was edited for C only:

This page is pretty helpful: http://www.geekpedia.com/tutorial39_Random-Number-Generation.html

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

//use this first function to seed the random number generator, 
//call this before any of the other functions 
void initrand() 
{ 
    srand((unsigned)(time(0))); 
} 

//generates a psuedo-random float between 0.0 and 0.999... 
float randfloat() 
{ 
    return rand()/(float(RAND_MAX)+1); 
} 

//generates a psuedo-random float between 0.0 and max 
float randfloat(float max) 
{ 
    return randfloat()*max; 
} 

//generates a psuedo-random float between min and max 
float randfloat(float min, float max) 
{ 
    if (min>max) 
        return randfloat()*(min-max)+max;     
    else 
        return randfloat()*(max-min)+min; 
} 

//generates a psuedo-random double between 0.0 and 0.999... 
double randdouble() 
{ 
    return rand()/(double(RAND_MAX)+1); 
} 

//generates a psuedo-random double between 0.0 and max 
double randdouble(double max) 
{ 
    return randdouble()*max; 
} 

//generates a psuedo-random double between min and max 
double randdouble(double min, double max) 
{ 
    if (min>max) 
        return randdouble()*(min-max)+max;     
    else 
        return randdouble()*(max-min)+min; 
} 

int main()
{
    for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
        printf("%f\n", randdouble(-1,3));
}
```

### Output sample:

```
2.360751
0.577532
2.132397
2.193760
2.646589
-0.209795
0.340891
2.072918
0.111099
1.215880
```

(note the range: -1..3)

Comment: @AndrejsCainikovs: neither **[were the tags](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/7978759/2)**. C++ is hardly ever pure C

Comment: Don't know about C++. In C it is mostly often wrong to use `float` when `double` can do the same thing :-)

Answer (score 2):

Following will give you a float in range between `-max/2` up to `+max/2`:

```
float max = 5000;
float r = max * ((float)rand()/(float)RAND_MAX - 0.5);
```

Comment: It will have a quite strange distribution, having the constant in the numerator and the function result in the denominator...

Comment: Thanks, now it should look better.

Comment: Very fine - except that it MIGHT impact precision that you mis `float` and `double`, depending on the `RAND_MAX` value. As it is not guaranteed to be a power of 2, it would be better to use `double` here as well (mantissa 52+1 instead of merely 23+1 bits) resp. to generally use `double` here in order not to lose any precision. Nevertheless, one cast at either `rand()` or `RAND_MAX` should be enough - the other operand then happens to get taken with this.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Boost.Random:

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/boost_random.html

You can get float random values doing this way:

```
boost::mt19937 base_rng;
boost::uniform_01<> u01;
boost::variate_generator<boost::mt19937&, boost::uniform_01<> > rng(base_rng, u01);

rng(); // draws a random number
```

Please note that random number generation facilities are now available in the new C++ standard:

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/latest-doxygen/a01617.html

Comment: Boost is C++. The question was about C.

Comment: @glglgl On the other hand the presence of the C++ tag is misleading.

Comment: Really? Seriously, the question bears the c++ tag too, so please check everything before downvoting!

Comment: Out of the box, boost.random generates random integers. You don't show how this can be used to generate random floats.

Comment: The question says "How can i generate float random values in C"

Comment: The question was re-tagged since being asked. Unfortunately, many apply _both_ C/C++ tags incorrectly to get their question in front of a larger audience.

Answer (score 0):

The GNU scientific library has a few methods.

http://www.gnu.org/s/gsl/manual/html_node/Random-number-generator-algorithms.html

Even if you can't use it due to licensing it should give you the names of a few too google for.

The boost random library (C++) uses lagged fibonacci and ranlux algorithms for doubles and floats, so they may be another option for you. (The methods not the boost library as it is C++ )

These techniques usually give you results in the range 0 -- 1. By using `R = rmin + v* (rmax-rmin)` where v is in 0 -- 1 you will get `R` in rmin -- rmax

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
rand() / (double)RAND_MAX /* 0 <= random number <= 1 */
rand() / (RAND_MAX + 1.0) /* 0 <= random number < 1 */
```

for a random number between 0 and 1.
Then multiply by your desired range and add for the initial value.

For instance, to get random numbers `0 <= X < 4.2`

```
double tmp = rand() / (RAND_MAX + 1.0)
X = tmp * 4.2;
```

to get random numbers `-21.1 <= X <= 37.5`

```
double tmp = rand() / (double)RAND_MAX
X = tmp * (37.5 + 21.1);
X = X - 21.1;
```

Answer (score -1):

The simplest method I know:

```
int randNum = rand();
float floatRand = randNum/RAND_MAX;
```

floatRand is a random float in [0,1]. However, the resolution of this method is limited by RAND_MAX..

[EDIT]:
to get negative values, generate another random number and if its greater than RAND_MAX/2, multiply the former by (-1).

Comment: thank you, but i need the possibilty that the algorithm generate also negative values...

Comment: -1: `randNum` is of type `int`; `RAND_MAX` is as `"integer constant expression"`. Dividing the first by the second will **always** evaluate to `0`.

Answer (score -1):

This will generate random [any representable float]:

```
#include <stdio.h>

float randfdev(void)
    {
    float tmp;
    int fd = open("/dev/urandom",O_RDONLY);
    read(fd,&tmp,sizeof tmp);
    return tmp;
    }
```

Note:

- no error checking
- assumes IEEE floating point, although other formats should work
- will produce NaNs, subnormals, infinitys, etc